# How to recreate / reinstantiate an object in python 2.7

Tags: python, oop

I am looking for a way to recreate / reinstantiate an object in python,    because I want the object to have a default attribute in each loop.

```
for case in all_case:

    # I want an object to be newly created  / reinstantiated in each loop 
    pda = PushDownAutomata()
    print pda.evaluate(case, debug=False)

    # I already added "del pda" but it does not work
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: There is no need to delete. This code already creates a new object in each iteration.

Comment: but the class variable in an object doesn't get a new attribute, it's always have the previous object value

Comment: Because that's what class variables do. Deleting things wouldn't change that. If you don't want that, use an instance variable instead.

Comment: for example?? thanks for comment btw

Comment: understand, i get it haha, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that class attributes are not the same as instance attributes.
for example:

```
class A(object):

    a = None # this is a class attribute

    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b # b is an instance attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by the following code. I was using a class variable before - changing it to an instance variable solved the issue:

```
# before (class variable)
class PushDownAutomata():
    stack = []
    state = 'q1'

# after (instance variable)
class PushDownAutomata():
    def __init__():
        self.stack = []
        self.state = 'q1'
```